# Effective way to handle open-ended student feedback?

Tags: teaching, feedback, technology, course-evaluation

I regularly use a short start/stop/continue-survey on my students to be able to improve my teaching skills. I get a lot of informative data that helps me, but there's a lot of work involved in digging that information out by hand.

Does anyone have any best practice recommendations on how to handle open-ended feedback?

Is there a way of using text analytics to show points of strong consensus?